# SQL Hadoop Hive vs Toad for DB2 - Multiple Distinct Counts

Tags: sql, hive, db2, toad

I am trying to construct a query for Toad, however, the following is not working.

```
select count (distinct t.column1, t.column2)
from schema.table
;
```

However, the above query works just fine in Hadoop Hive. Any suggestions on refining the query so it works for Toad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulating the behavior is a little tricky.  The safest method is probably:

```
select sum(case when seqnum = 1 and column1 is not null and column2 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by column1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

(The `order by` column doesn't matter.  Many databases require one so I regularly include it.)

This version works for any database, not just DB2.

The issue is that Hive does not count a row if *any* of the values are `NULL`, which this takes into account.

The use of `select distinct` in a subquery is close, but it counts `NULL` values -- and that change may not be appropriate for other columns in your query.

Concatenating columns together comes closer.  However you have problems when there are overlapping values (say '12'/'3' and '1'/'23').

Answer (score 2):

Try to concatenate them:

```
select count(distinct concat(t.column1, t.column2))
from schema.table t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
select count(1)
from (select distinct t.column1, t.column2 from schema.table) as t1
;
```